# Ignoring subproject while building fat JAR of root project

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a root project from which I want to build a fat JAR with sbt-assembly. It does have a subproject, which depends on root which I want to have ignored for the fat JAR (as if it didn't exist). How do I do this?

Basically I want the root project packages as if there was no `localMode` subproject from the `build.sbt` in Try 1.

## Try 1

My `build.sbt` is

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := "myprojectname"
version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"

mainClass in(Compile, run) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
mainClass in(Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Provided
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % Test

lazy val localMode = project.
  in(file("localMode")).
  dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname_local",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Compile,
    mainClass in(Compile, run) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample"),
    mainClass in(Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
  )

fullClasspath in assembly := { 
  (fullClasspath in assembly).value diff 
  (fullClasspath in assembly in localMode).value 
}
```

currently I get the error message:

```
[error] (localMode/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice/jars/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar:com/google/inject/AbstractModule.class
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:com/google/inject/AbstractModule.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice/jars/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar:com/google/inject/Binder.class
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:com/google/inject/Binder.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice/jars/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar:com/google/inject/ConfigurationException.class
[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:com/google/inject/ConfigurationException.class

and so on...
```

If I command `sbt root/assembly` I get

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: root (similar: reboot, boot, project)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: root (similar: products)
[error] root/assembly
[error]     ^
```

## Try 2

My second `build.sbt` cannot be build:

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8",
  mainClass in(Compile, run) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample"),
  mainClass in(Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample"),
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % Test
)

lazy val root = project.
  in(file("root")).
  dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Provided,
    mainClass in assembly := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
  )

lazy val localMode = project.
  in(file("localMode")).
  dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname_local",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Compile
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with the `assembly::fullClasspath` setting. By [default](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/v0.14.3/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/AssemblyPlugin.scala#L97) it's set to `fullClasspath or (fullClasspath in Runtime)`. So probably you can do something like this:

```
fullClasspath in assembly := { 
  (fullClasspath in assembly).value diff 
  (fullClasspath in assembly in localMode).value 
}
```

In the absence of details about you particular project configuration, I guess `localMode` is the name of the subproject you want to exclude.

**UPDATE**

There are some problems with the `build.sbt` in your Try 2:
 - you don't add common settings to your projects
 - "root" is the one in the, well, root of your project dir (i.e. `in file(".")`)
 - if you explicitly define `root` project, the other one should depend on it, instead of the `RootProject`, which is just a way to refer to the "implicitly" defined root project

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8",
  mainClass in(Compile, run) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample"),
  mainClass in(Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample"),
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % Test
)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Provided,
    mainClass in assembly := Some("com.mywebsite.MyExample")
  )

lazy val localMode = project. // by default the name of the project val is the name of its base directory
  dependsOn(root).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myprojectname_local",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % Compile
  )
```

Check sbt docs on [Multi-project builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html). To your questions about the `root` project, there's a chapter called [Default root project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project). Now with these fixes, does `root/assembly` work as expected?

Comment: That did not help. I added infos to my error message.

Comment: @Make42 you should post your `build.sbt` as well. Probably this problem is resolvable with just configuring your subprojects properly.

Comment: Have you tried to call it with the project scope? like `root/assembly`.

Comment: If I write `sbt root/assembly`, I get the error you can read in the question now. If I write `sbt myprojectname/assembly`, I get the already known error. I am not sure what `RootProject(file("."))` is referencing to.

Comment: I tried to put everything (except `libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % Provided)`) that in a `lazy val commonSettings` and added this to `localMode` as settings and made a `lazy val root` project that also used `commonSettings` and added `libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % Provided)`. I hope you get the idea. However I can't compile anything (neither `root` nor the top-project directly`) now. Reason: It can't find the Spark dependencies now, so the classes cannot be found.

Comment: can you show me this last `build.sbt` with explicit `root` project?

Comment: Done. Maybe you can explain a little: What does `dependsOn(RootProject(file(".")))` mean?

Comment: Also I don't quite get how this "root" works: Is this just another subproject or a special one? What is the default project, if I don't mention any project, so if I write just `sbt assembly`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
aggregate in (Compile, assembly) := false
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working. I get the usual "deduplicate" error.